# Regex for find: table.insert(x,y,z) And replace: x[y]=z

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Regex for find:

```
table.insert(x,y,z)
```

And replace:

```
x[y]=z
```

Sample code:

Find:

```
table.insert(RL_LostWiggleTool.widgetDoubleClickTbl, 0, RL_LostWiggleTool.firstClickTime)
```

Replace:

```
RL_LostWiggleTool.widgetDoubleClickTbl[0] =     L_LostWiggleTool.firstClickTime
```

Comment: It appears you forgot to include a question in your question. Moreover, you've tagged it with no less than three different regex engines, which one are you *really* using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
table\.insert\(([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pU2pU3/2)